# Convert message and signature to BouncyCastle CMSSignedData object

Tags: java, rsa, digital-signature, bouncycastle, pkcs#7

I have an X509CertificateObject, a matching RSAPublicKey and managed to create a byte array containing a valid digital certificate for some message object also as a byte array.

Unfortunately the system I'm building upon only accepts `CMSSignedData` objects as input.
How do I convert my basic building blocks into such a valid `CMSSignedData` object?

Background:  I'm experimenting with Java Bouncy Castle RSA blind signatures according to [this example](http://java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/Security/Bouncy-Castle/org/bouncycastle/crypto/test/PSSBlindTest.java.htm) (digest is SHA512) and need to feed the result into the standard signature processing.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll probably want to sign your data with a private key. The idea being that the signature should be something only you can create. One you get that the rest should be as follows:

```
X509Certificate signingCertificate = getSigningCertificate();
//The chain of certificates that issued your signing certificate and so on
Collection<X509Certificate> certificateChain = getCertificateChain();
PrivateKey pk = getPrivateKey();
byte[] message = "SomeMessage".getBytes();

CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
certificateChain.add(signingCertificate);
generator.addCertificates(new CollectionStore(certificateChain));

JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder jcaDigestProvider = new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder();
jcaDigestProvider.setProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder singerInfoGenerator = new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(jcaDigestProvider.build());

AlgorithmIdentifier sigAlgId = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find("SHA1withRSA");
AlgorithmIdentifier digAlgId = new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find(sigAlgId);
AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKeyParam = PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(pk.getEncoded());
ContentSigner cs = new BcRSAContentSignerBuilder(sigAlgId, digAlgId).build(privateKeyParam);

SignerInfoGenerator sig = singerInfoGenerator.build(cs, signingCertificate);
generator.addSignerInfoGenerator(sig);

CMSSignedData data = generator.generate(new CMSProcessableByteArray(message), true);
```